# Flask text & file upload in the same form - Results in an empty dictionary

Tags: jquery, python, flask

So I have an HTML form with a few input text fields, but now I want to include file uploading in the same form as well.

I saw in other posts in here that using a FormData object would do the job for me. However when I implement it the dict that I receive in Flask is empty.

Here is the HTML form. The button that calls the action is outside the form - I handle it with Ajax as I don't want to refresh the page.

```
<form action="{{ url_for('configure') }}" method="post" enctype="multiform/form-data" id="form_withtabs">
    <div class="row">
        <br>
        <div class="col-lg-2">
            <label>
                <input type="text" id="input_username" name="username" class"form-control" placeholder="Username" >
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2">
            <label>
                <input type="password" name="password" class"form-control" placeholder="Password" />
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3">
            <input class="pull-right" type="text" name="project_name" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Select a name for the project" placeholder="Project Name" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-5">
            <input type="file" name="config_file" class="pull-right" />
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

```
        var thisformData = new FormData($('#form_withtabs'));

        $.ajax({
            url: "/configure",
            data: thisformData,
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData: false,
            async: false,
            success: function(response) {
                var $link_addr = $(response).filter('#link').html();
                $('body').removeClass("loading");
                $(".alert-danger").html($link_addr);
                $(".alert-danger").show();
                return true;
            }
```

And this is the function that handles the request.

```
@app.route('/configure', methods=['POST'])
def configure():
    print request.form
    if request.method == 'POST':
        #request the file from 
        file = request.files['config_file']
        if file:
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            #app.config["UPLOAD_FOLDER"] is defined in flask_define.py
            file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
```

The result that I get from pressing submit is

```
ImmutableMultiDict([])
```

And `400 Bad Request`

Can somebody help me find my mistake?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution.

Instead of using `var thisformData = new FormData($('#form_withtabs'));`

I tried using `var form = document.querySelector('#form_withtabs');
            var formData = new FormData(form);`

At the end that solved my problem and Flask now receives everything.